# How well did Lenin and Hitler knew each other? Were they some sort of friends?

Tags: hitler, lenin

I read a couple of short articles about Lenin and Hitler met each other, and there is a picture, a drawing from Emma Lowenstramm - which's by the historians' opinion is most probably authentic - where they played chess in Austria in 1909. Here is a [link](http://www.mullocksauctions.co.uk/lot-19408-hitler_etching_by_emma_lowenstamm_vienna_1909_showing.html) to the article of the mentioned picture, thanks to neubau.

By historical timeline it could be possible since by then Hitler wasn't famous at all, he was in Austria, later after the WW1 he joined to DAP (Workers Party of Germany), by Lenin's side, then he was in exile from Russia because of failed 1905 revolution and he spent some time in Austria and Switzerland as well, and he attended to various communist congresses all around Europe.

Ideologically Lenin and Hitler had many common points. They both were socialist, they both were autocratic persons, they were both interested in politics.

**Were they friends at any level?** It seems from the articles I found by simple google search that at least they most probably met a few times.

Comment: "[the picture] is most probably authentic". Apart from the fact that you fail to name the historian's name, what does authentic mean? That Emma Lowenstramm effectively painted it, or that it is a document of a supposed meeting between Lenin and Hitler (which at the time would have been 21 at most)?

Comment: could you reference the picture somehow? Could you provide citations for any of the references you consulted? Much easier to judge the veracity of a reference if you can... consult the reference.

Comment: This question is rubbish.

Comment: Is this the source?  http://www.mullocksauctions.co.uk/lot-19408-hitler_etching_by_emma_lowenstamm_vienna_1909_showing.html

Comment: I'd disagree it's "opinion-based", **the question is clearly defined, unambiguous, and answerable**. Looking at the only answer, it seems the answer is clearly "no".

Comment: @Bregalad I would accept that answer if it is clear.

Comment: Lenin beat Hitler twice at chess, which explains Hitler's hatred of everything Russian or socialist. [/sarcasm]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The picture referred to, an etching, was put up for auction in 2009, according to the New York Times,

> accompanied by a 300 page dossier of evidence painstakingly compiled by Felix Edenhofer the present vendor’s father.  [(auction house website)](http://www.mullocksauctions.co.uk/lot-19408-hitler_etching_by_emma_lowenstamm_vienna_1909_showing.html)

The Times article ([link here](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/09/30/arts/design/30hitler.html?_r=0)) shows that there are many holes in the story.  It quotes authoritative historians like Richard Evans and Richard Pipes, who judge the picture to be an obvious fake.

> Richard J. Evans, regius professor of modern history at Cambridge, who wrote a three-volume history of the Third Reich, said he had little doubt that the chess match was a fiction. “No, it could not have taken place,” he said in an interview.

Problems mentioned in the article – Hitler looks too old, Lenin is supposedly wearing a disguise but in fact he never did so at this point, Lenin had given up chess and Hitler probably never played, there was no reason for them to sign the picture, there is no record of Hitler taking art lessons, etc.

It’s also suspicious that there is no documentary trace of  the artist in Vienna.

Brigitte Hamann in “Hitler’s Vienna” has gone through the archival record for Hitler’s contacts at the time.  In fact, he did visit the house of a cultured Jewish bourgeois family in 1908.  His roommate at the time, August Kubizek, played the viola and was sometimes invited to the home of Dr. Rudolf Jahoda to fill out a string quartet at musical soirées.  Once he brought Hitler along, and the 19-year-old was largely a silent observer.

There is no Lowenstamm/stramm in Hamann’s index.